# How do I add a shared folder between an Arch host and a Debian guest on QEMU (I've already tried a few things)?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, file-sharing

I just installed a new Debian guest system on my Arch host and would like to transfer some files to it, so I wanted to create a shared folder. I installed the system using GNOME boxes, so I tried first this tutorial: https://www.debugpoint.com/share-folder-gnome-boxes/. I followed all the steps, but the folder did not appear in the system, probably because I'm using a VPN and when I go into the GNOME settings and turn on file sharing it only shows my VPN server as a possible network. So then I went into the system using Virtual Manager and tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.debugpoint.com/share-folder-virt-manager/, but when I try to add the new virtual hardware, XML configuration

```
<filesystem type="mount">
  <source dir="/home/alex/shared/debian"/>
  <target dir="shared"/>
  <driver type="virtiofs"/>
</filesystem>
```

then I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addhardware.py", line 1262, in _finish_cb
    failure = self._add_device(dev)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addhardware.py", line 1254, in _add_device
    self.vm.add_device(dev)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 618, in add_device
    self._redefine_xmlobj(xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 391, in _redefine_xmlobj
    self._redefine_xml_internal(origxml, newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 374, in _redefine_xml_internal
    self._define(newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1137, in _define
    self.conn.define_domain(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 554, in define_domain
    return self._backend.defineXML(xml)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4495, in defineXML
    raise libvirtError('virDomainDefineXML() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: virtiofs is not yet supported in session mode
```

And I didn't really find anything about that error that I understood enough to use. I just want a folder I can use to share files! How can I do that?